# Flask session cookies not persisting on browser close

Tags: python, session, cookies

I have made a flask app that relies on having session cookies for logging in. However, whenever I reopen my browser and visit http://localhost:5000/, the cookie disappears and I am logged out.

Here is some of my code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = <bytes object generated by os.urandom(24)>
app.config["PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME"] = timedelta(hours=1)


@app.route("/")
def login_redirect():
    if check_login(session, False):
        return redirect("/interface")
    return redirect("/login")


def check_login(session, requires_elevated):
    if "username" not in session:
        return False
    elif session["username"] == "admin":
        return True
    elif session["username"] == "regular" and not requires_elevated:
        return True
    return False
```

I didn't want to paste all of it because some if it is private, but if there is anything else I can include that may be helpful then let me know and I will do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `before_request` you need to set the session to be permanent so that it abides by your config setting:

```
@app.before_request
def setup():
    session.permanent = True
```