# I have to relogin Flask-framework website everytime I close and reopen the Chrome App on phone

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

Whenever I close and reopen the Chrome App on Phone, and go to my Flask-framework website, It always ask me to login. Everything is fine with Chrome browser on a computer. I don't need to relogin everytime I close Chrome browser, even restart the computer.

I need to keep my account login. How does Flask store the cookies? Am I missing something on Mobile web version ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this setting for your Flask app.

```
@app.before_request
def setup():
    session.permanent = True
```

Reference: [Flask session cookies not persisting on browser close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182978/flask-session-cookies-not-persisting-on-browser-close)